# ftplugin default configuration

Tags: vim, ftplugin

I have found several topics that come close to matching my issue but, does not completely solve my problem. I have read about, and tried researching, the .vim/ftplugin/ and .vim/after/ftplugin/ methods of dealing with several filetypes and additively changing the configurations. I have also tried overriding a ~/.vimrc config file with a ../ftplugin to no avail.

**Question:** What is the best solution for setting a default .vimrc iff one does not exist in the .vim/ftplugin/ directory? I have a standard vim configuration that I would like to apply if the filetype loaded is not one of which I have a **filetype**.vim configuration in the ftplugin directory.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not *the* filetype configuration, only individual options, mappings, etc. in `~/.vim/ftplugin/`, and defining a default depends on the particular type of configuration. The most common use case is *buffer-local options*, like `'softtabstop'` for example, and dealing with that is straightforward:

In your `~/.vimrc`, you define the global default via `:set softtabstop=4`. Now if you don't want that for Java files, you put `:setlocal softtabstop=0` in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/java.vim`. Use of the `after` directory is recommended because the default `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/java.vim` might set a filetype-specific default, and you'd override that this way.